# How do to pass parameter to a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I pass a parameter from my return statement to the custom hook, I have created everything but just the method to pass the parameter to the custom hook is my problem.

```
  const {
      geodata: address,
      isPending,
      geoerror,}
    = useGeo(latitude, longitude);
```

You see `useGeo` that's the custom hook where I want to pass latitude and longitude (This works but I don't know to pass the parameter from the return statement)

So I tried method like this:

```
  const getAddApi = (latitude, longitude) => useGeo(latitude, longitude);
```

and in the return statement I tried this below but it didnt work I keep getting `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

```
<Text>{getAddApi(item.latitude, item.longitude).geodata}</Text>
```

Comment: The component that's using this custom hook, is it a function component or a class component?

Comment: Its a functional component

Answer (score 3):

Custom hook is follows:

- a function
- call at least one build-in hook inside
- used inside a function component (this is your error)

Suppose I design a custom hook like this,

```
  const useGeo = (latitude) => {
    const [state] = useState(latitude)
    return state
  }
```

It's a simple function with input `latitude` and return `state`. Now you can use it in a function component.

```
  const Title = () => {
    const s = useGeo(273)
    ...
  }
```

This is what a custom hook about. It's used mainly for algorithm refactoring. If you want to know more about input and output, just ask what you normally do for a function. The rest is the definition of the hooks  that you have to meet which i listed above.

Comment: Okay I get you, but how then can I pass data (coordinates) from my api to a function (reverse geocoding) and then return the output for every specific coordinate. What I mean is that I created a `Flatlist` from my api data, part of that data are coordinates which I need reverse geocoding to get the address (I can do that), But I can get it to show back on the flatlist